# Is there a .Net wrapper for Firefox or Chrome to crawl webpages?

Tags: c#, .net, firefox, google-chrome, web-crawler

Is there a simple .Net wrapper for Firefox or Chrome so that I could implement a web crawler and other web stuff?
I might need post-form functionality also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see: http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/

Gecko is the engine that's used in Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

The Mono project has a .NET webbrowser that allows you to use either the Gecko (Firefox) or Webkit (Chrome, Safari) rendering engines under the hood, exposing either as a clean, well-designed .NET API. See [Mono.WebBrowser](http://www.mono-project.com/WebBrowser).

Answer (score 2):

Skybound has released an open source .NET wrapper for Firefox at http://geckofx.org/